# multipleselect is forgeting selected values after proceed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-select2

Multiplyselect is forgetting owners values after searching.
After proceed i got params[:search] and params[:owners] but only input for search is filled-in. This is my code.

```
def index
 @all_owners = Owner.select('distinct name').pluck(:name)
 @animal = Animal.search(params[:search])
 @animal = @animals.joins(:owners).where("owners.name IN (?) ", params[:owners].present? ? params[:owners] : @owners)
end

#------------------------------------------

<%= form_tag animals_path, :method => 'get' do %>
 <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]%>
 <%= select_tag :owners, options_for_select(@all_owners),id: "multiselect-id", multiple: true %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil  %>
<% end %>

<% @aminals.each do |animal| %>
 <%= animal.name %>
 <%= animal.owners.map(&:name).join(', ') %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#multiselect-id').select2();
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify the currently selected values in the `select_tag`. This is done e.g. by a second argument to the `options_for_select` helper, i.e. something like:  `options_for_select(@all_owners, params[:owners] || @owners)`.

See the [docs here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select).

Comment: Thanks! I tried before something like this: 

<%= select_tag :owners, params[:owners], options_for_select(@all_owners),id: "multiselect-id", multiple: true %> 

and it wasn't throwing an error. Replacing params[:owners] to options_for_select fixed the problem.

Solution:

<%= select_tag :owners, options_for_select(@all_owners, params[:owners]),id: "multiselect-id", multiple: true %>